# Translate string with python babel doesn't work

Tags: python, internationalization, python-babel

I have this python line

```py
raise ValueError(_(u'Your password must be {} of characters or longer.'.format(MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH)))
```

I added it to the PO file:

```py
msgid "Your password must be {} of characters or longer."
msgstr "Votre mot de passe doit être {} de caractères ou plus."
```

I compiled it but it doesn't translate it.

All other translations work on this site except this one.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the `.po` file you need to keep the `%s` format.

like this:

```py
msgid "Your password must be %s characters or longer."
msgstr "Votre mot de passe doit être %s caractères ou plus."
```

Or with the python-brace-format

```py
#: foo/bar.py:32 
#, python-brace-format
msgid "Your password must be {n} characters or longer."
msgstr "Votre mot de passe doit être {n} caractères ou plus."
```

Answer (score 0):

```
raise ValueError("Your password must be " +str(MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH)+" of characters or longer")


raise ValueError(u'Your password must be {} of characters or longer.'.format(MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH))
```

i just removed one _ because i don't think it was needed.

[image]

Comment: At least at some words to your answer explaining what the problem was and what you did

Comment: Whatever you did, write it in the answer. Otherwise, readers will have to compare the codes character by character

Comment: @JainilPatel changed to raise ValueError(u'Your password must be {} of characters or longer.'.format(MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH)) and still it doesn't work.

Comment: @JainilPatel if I change to your first proposal what should I write at the po file? "raise ValueError("Your password must be " +str(MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH)+" of characters or longer")"

Comment: @JainilPatel po is the translation file see https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/extensions/translating-extensions.html. my question was about the translation, I have no problem with displaying it in English

Comment: @JainilPatel to other language, in this example Hebrew

Comment: @JainilPatel whatever language, it doesn't matter.  see docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/extensions/translating-extensions.html

Comment: @JainilPatel msgid "Your password must be {} of characters or longer." msgstr "הסיסמה חייבת להכיל מינימום {} תווים"

Comment: str("Your password must be " +str(MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH)+" of characters or longer")

Comment: @JainilPatel I don't understand what do you mean. What should I write in the po file?